# symmetric and regular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

A is symmetric, regular matrix. I need to prove that A ^ 17 is symmetric too.
There is some sentence about symmetric matrix I can use here?

Comment: What do you mean by "sentence about symmetric matrix"?

Comment: Do you know that $(AB)' = (B') (A')$ , for matrices $A$ and $B$ in general?

Comment: @kimchilover I don't understand how it helps..

Comment: So what _have_ you tried already?  What _do you know_ about this problem.  Or about symmetric matrices?  Can you answer the (presumably simpler) problem about $A^2$?

Answer (score 0):

Well, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix) says that for integer $n \space,A^{n}$ is symmetric  if $A$ is symmetric. But if you want really to prove that, you can use formula which says that matrix is diagonalizable if and only if has n different linear independent eigenvectors. It means that matrix is symmilar to some diagonal matrix D. And matrix S is matrix that has eigenvectors from matrix A as colums.  $\Rightarrow A=S\cdot D \cdot S^{-1}$
$$A^{n}=\underbrace{S\cdot D \cdot S^{-1}\cdot S\cdot D \cdot S^{-1}\cdot S\cdot D \cdot S^{-1}...}\\ _{n times}$$ $$A^{n}=S\cdot D^{n}\cdot S^{-1}$$ I think it is the easiest way to prove that matrix $\space A^{n}$ is symmetric  if $A$ is symmetric for some integer $n$.

Comment: You can use the fact that $(AB)'=B'A'$ to calculate $(A^n)' = (A')^n=A^n$, knowing nothing about diagonalizability.